# guess_language module is giving UNKNOWN

Tags: python

I installed (I am in Windows 7, but I am using a `virtualenv` with Python 2.7.5):

```
pip install pyenchant
pip install 3to2
pip install https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/downloads/guess_language-spirit-0.5.tar.bz2
```

and did:

```
>>> from guess_language import guess_language
>>> guess_language("Hello World")
u'UNKNOWN'
```

Why am I getting `u'UNKNOWN'`?

[This is the project site](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language).

Comment: Have you tried the example `guess_language("Hello, World!")` verbatim?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I tried, but the same result.

Comment: Could be a bug with the library. Consider contacting the developer.

Comment: May be you don't have appropriate dictionaries installed?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal which dictionary do I need?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#windows-users - rather strange though, because it mentions 'en_US' being installed by default.

Comment: @Trengot are you also in windows7?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) for this. it'll be much easier in nltk.

```
import nltk

STOPWORDS_DICT = {lang: set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(lang))
                  for lang in nltk.corpus.stopwords.fileids()}

def get_language(text):
    words = set(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text.lower()))
    return max(((lang, len(words & stopwords))
                for lang, stopwords in STOPWORDS_DICT.items()),
               key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Now see the code in action.

```
In [28]: get_language('hello world')
Out[28]: 'swedish'

In [30]: get_language('stackoverflow is a nice website')
Out[30]: 'english'
```

problem is if the sample text is very small it'll give wrong result.

The code is taken from [this](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python/cheap-language-detection-nltk/) site.

Comment: with nltk, i need to download all language modules as well, right?

Comment: the tokenization method itself (of nltk) is dependent on the language, then how can it detect languages. This method is unreliable.